# table with multiple row / header have some fill remaning space

Tags: html, css

I have a simple example of a table with multi row at different levels. The issue is that some of the rows won't expand till the end:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th>a title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <th>sub content</th>
      <th>sub content 2</th>
      <th>sub conetnt 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thread>
</table>
```

as you can see the title border is limiting itself, and all css selectors I tried to get it to expand it's remaining space failed me.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just specify a **colspan** value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the problem correctly, you want the underline under title to go across in the same way as the underline(s) of the th cells. We can go one step further and have the title in one merged cell created from the equivalent of 3 th cells.

This snippet does this by using the attribute `colspan` in the th element in the first row in the thead [Note: there appears to be a typo in the question's code - thread instead of thead].

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">a title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <th>sub content</th>
      <th>sub content 2</th>
      <th>sub conetnt 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thread>
</table>
```